# What group are the group of symmetries for the shown figure

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question based on the post below:-

[What group are the group of symmetries of these figures isomorphic to - Fraleigh p. 85 Theorem 8.23, 24, 26](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634992/what-group-are-the-group-of-symmetries-of-these-figures-isomorphic-to-fraleigh)

Fig (a) is isomorphic to Z2 as per the answer. Z2 consists of 0,1. How is this isomorphic to the figure shown, which looks like Y?

Any help/hints is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple when you see it. Take the point i) as the left top of the big Y and ii) as the right top point, iii) as the bottom of the big Y.

If you rotate the Y 2 times (180 deg) along the tail of Y the i) and ii) will come back to the initial position which explains order of 2.

You can't rotate this in any other way. Hence it's isomorphic to Z2.